Existence of limit of power series
We have the following power series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{3^n}-z^{2\cdot3^n}}{n}
$$
We know it has radius of convergence $R=1$ (I already asked about this in another post, Radius of convergence of power series. for reference). We can also see that when $z=1$, series converges trivially to $0$. The aim is to prove that the following limit
$$
\lim_{z \to 1} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{3^n}-z^{2\cdot3^n}}{n}
$$
doesn't exist.
I proceeded as follows:
Firstly, we consider the sequence of points in the border of the disc of convergence $(w_m)_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ given as $w_m:= \cos\frac{\pi}{3^m} + i\sin\frac{\pi}{3^m}$, it is clear that $w_m \longrightarrow 1$ as $m \longrightarrow \infty$
(as $ \lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{3^m}=0 $). For every $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ I defined
$$
\gamma_{m,n}:=\frac{{w_m}^{3^n}-{w_m}^{2\cdot3^n}}{n}.
$$
Using De Moivre's formula, we can express $\gamma_{m,n}$ as
$$
\gamma_{m,n}=\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{3^m}3^n) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{3^m}3^n)-
[\cos(\frac{\pi}{3^m}2\cdot3^n) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{3^m}2\cdot3^n)]}{n}=
\frac{(\cos(\pi3^{n-m})-\cos(2\pi3^{n-m}))+i(\sin(\pi3^{n-m})-\sin(2\pi3^{n-m}))}{n}
$$
Note that if $n > m$, then $3^{n-m}$ is a positive power of $3$, in particular, it's odd. Then $\pi3^{n-m}$ is an odd multiple of $\pi$ and $2\pi3^{n-m}$ is an even multiple of $\pi$. When $n=m, 3^{n-m}=1$, which is still odd so the result holds up, and so we consider $n \geq m$. In that case,
$$
\cos(\pi3^{n-m})=-1, \cos(2\pi3^{n-m})=1 \\
\sin(\pi3^{n-m})=\sin(2\pi3^{n-m})=0
$$
so given $m\in\mathbb{N},\forall n\geq m$,
$$
\gamma_{m,n}=\frac{-2}{n}.
$$
Now, I used that for every $m \in \mathbb{N}$ the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\gamma_{m,n}$ converges or diverges if and only if the same series starting from index
$n=m: \sum_{n=m}^{\infty}\gamma_{m,n}$ converges or diverges respectively, and as $\gamma_{m,n}=\frac{-2}{n} \forall n\geq m$, then the series is
$\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}\frac{-2}{n}$, which diverges to $-\infty$; and so, the first series is also divergent.
Then,
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{w_m}^{3^n}-{w_m}^{2\cdot3^n}}{n}=-\infty, (w_m\longrightarrow 1)
$$
From here, it should follow that the limit doesn't exist since if we approach $1$ from points in the segment $(0,1)$, then the limit should be $0$, but I'm not really sure about this last step. Is this really true? The only way I see it is if I could change the limit with the summation order, and I guess this applies if the hypotheses of dominated convergence are fulfilled, but how would one prove that? Maybe that isn't necessary and the result is a direct consecuence of the series converging trivially to $0$ when $z=1$, but I can't see that either.
Also, let me know about any incorrect steps in my procedure. Thanks :)

Sure.  This is a solution verification site.  Just post all your scratch work and we'll pick through it and find/correct any holes/errors.

Before asing any questions search it in approach zero website : https://approach0.xyz/search/
